# Strange output formed by testing a combinations of sums or products in c

Tags: c

I have a problem with a simple code. i want to have all products and sums of a specific number for EX 4 -> 0+4 1+3 2+2 3+1 4+0. for the sum so I made this code to do it:

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>

 typedef struct{
 unsigned int x;
 unsigned int y;
 }str;

 const int MAX = 200000;

 int main(int argc,char *argv[]){
 int s=atoi(argv[1]);
 if(s<0 || s>MAX){
    printf("errore nummero incompatibile!\n");
    exit(-1);       
 }
 str sum;
 int n=MAX;
 for (sum.x=0;sum.x<n;sum.x++){
    for (sum.y=0;sum.y<n;sum.y++){
        if(strcmp(argv[2],"+")==0){
            if(sum.x+sum.y==s){
                printf("%d + %d = %d\n",sum.x,sum.y,s);
            }
        }else{
            if(sum.x*sum.y==s){
                printf("%d * %d = %d\n",sum.x,sum.y,s);
            }
        }
    }
 }
 exit(-1);
 }
```

the argv[1] is the number to testand the argv[2] is the mode (Sum or product)

here is the product output of 44 *:

```
1 * 44 = 44
2 * 22 = 44
4 * 11 = 44
11 * 4 = 44
22 * 2 = 44
44 * 1 = 44
25266 * 169990 = 44
33998 * 126330 = 44
42110 * 101994 = 44
50532 * 84995 = 44
50997 * 84220 = 44
63165 * 67996 = 44
67996 * 63165 = 44
84220 * 50997 = 44
84995 * 50532 = 44
101994 * 42110 = 44
126330 * 33998 = 44
167378 * 179622 = 44
169990 * 25266 = 44
179622 * 167378 = 44`
```

it gives the correct output but then it starts giving more numbers. these are the same each time i run it. what is this and how can i stop this?

Comment: the value in argc should be checked to assure the desired 2 parameters exist before actually trying to access those parameter.  and if they do not exist, then the code should display a 'usage' message and exit with error (-1)

Comment: the two 'for' statements are limited by MAX rather than 's'.

Comment: the '#include <string.h> header file is missing, so the call to strcmp() is not passed the proper parameters.   The struct has 'unsigned' fields but the working values are 'int', so the compiler raises several warnings about comparions between signed and unsigned integers.    Suggest; enable all warnings, re-compile the code, fix the warnings, and re-post the code

Comment: after modifying the code per the above comments, it works correctly for both '*' and '+'  however, there is a severe limitation on the upper max value (which is only seen when '*' is used)

Comment: @user3629249 everything workes fine for me now...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're iterating through every number until `MAX`, causing you overflows along the way ([See vitaut's answer for the explaination of your issue and how to prevent overflow in your case, he explained that very well.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30033616/4117075)). That's not necessary. When you try to find each combinaisons of multiplication of 2 integer, you just have to iterate until said number, or MAX if the number is too large.
Try to change

```
  int n=MAX;
```

by :

```
 int n = s;
 if (s > MAX)
    int n=MAX;
```

Comment: For some reason it no longer shows the 1* 44 and 44*1, but at least the overflow's are gone

Comment: @CoderGuy That's normal. change `(sum.x=0;sum.x<n;sum.x++)` with `(sum.x=0;sum.x<=n;sum.x++)` Your initial loop stopped before checking for MAX.

Answer (score 2):

This is caused by [integer overflow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow):

```
25266 * 169990 == 4294967340
```

4294967340 is too large to be represented as `unsigned int` which is 32-bit on your platform. So the most significant bits that don't fit get discarded, effectively giving you the result modulo 2 to the power of 32:

```
4294967340 mod 2**32 == 44
```

You can detect overflow in `sum.x + sum.y` by checking if `sum.x > UINT_MAX - sum.y` and either leave the inner loop or do something else. Similar check can be done for multiplication.

Comment: the base problem is using MAX rather than s to set n  which this answer does not address

Comment: The question is about strange output which is caused by integer overflow.